# Looking for a way to use auto scheduling plugin on wordpress, with facebook auto-publish to page

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a hosted wordpress site that I currently have set up with the Facebook for wordpress plugin to post to my facebook page (not profile).  This is kind of essential for me as I post a lot and it saves me a ton of time.

Another thing that would save me a lot of time is a decent auto-schedule plugin for wordpress.  I tried Auto-Schedule posts which I love, but to add a post to the queue I have to "publish" it.  It then takes the post and queues it until the set parameters are fulfilled.

The only problem is that when I publish the page to enter the queue, it sends it to my facebook page.  Is there any workaround for this?  Another plugin for scheduling anyone knows of that avoids this?  I am reasonably knowledgeable about coding if a coding solution is available, I just don't know much about how the Facebook application works.  So if there's any kind of edit I can make to the Auto Schedule Posts plugin that'd be cool.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use wordpress's built in scheduling functionality?

Comment: I do but I post every hour so it'd save me a lot of time to not have to use those drop downs on every single post.  And I use a desktop editor that doesn't allow scheduling, so I have to send it as a draft, then go in and set all the times individually.

Comment: You should bring up your issue with the Facebook for Wordpress plugin publishing scheduled posts immediately on that plugin's support site: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook

Answer (score 0):

I just released this plugin to have a very simple way of auto-queueing posts: http://wordpress.org/plugins/queue-posts

Hope it will be of help to to some of you! :)